# If I don't want Pi to be calculated, what should I do?

Tags: syntax, numerical-value

```
Dt[0.04Cos[10Pi x]Cos[50Pi t]]
```

As the titile described, I don't want the Pi to be calculated. I just want it to exist in the form "Pi".
[image]

Comment: You could use `\[DoubledPi]` temporarily instead of `\[Pi]`, and make replacements afterwards if you need to e.g. plot them.

Comment: Try having nothing with a decimal point. Turn 0.04 into 4/100 and see if that is enough to leave Pi unchanged. Usually any decimal point will then turn all exact quantities into approximate quantities with their own decimal points.

Comment: `Dt[0.04 Cos[10 Pi x] Cos[50 Pi t] // Rationalize] // Simplify`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make `Pi` inert, you can wrap it with `Hold[]` or `HoldForm[]`.

`Dt[0.04 Cos[10 HoldForm[Pi] x] Cos[50 HoldForm[Pi] t]]`

[image]

Some details :

`Hold[exp]` prevents exp to be evaluated whatever exp is.

`HoldForm` is equivalent to `Hold` except that it is not visible in OutputForm.

If you do not want to change every  `Pi` manually, you can do :

```
 With[{Pi = HoldForm[Pi]},
    Dt[0.04 Cos[10 Pi x] Cos[50 Pi t]]
    ]
```

You can retrieve the numerical value of an expression containing some `HoldForm[Pi]` with `ReleaseHold` wrapped around the whole expression.